# vnstat: how can I change the day of the month to track my internet usage?

Tags: linux, terminal

My internet provider has put me on a 15 of the month billing cylcle.
I looked at the man pages. Couldn't find a way to change the cut off day on vnstat. 
I would like my month to reset on the 15, not the first.
Other than that, vnstat works really well for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I change the day of the month to track my internet usage?

Use the `MonthRotate` option in your configuration file, for example:

```
MonthRotate 15
```

> **MonthRotate**
>
> Day of month that months are expected to change. Usually set to 1 but
>   can be set to alternative values for example for tracking monthly
>   billed traffic where the billing period doesn't start on the first
>   day. Value range: 1..28 (vnstat and vnstatd only)

Source [vnstat.conf - vnStat configuration file - Linux Man Pages (5)](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-vnstat.conf/)

Note:

> Having been in contact by e-mail with vnstat's author, Teemu Toivola, it was revealed that [as I suspected/hoped for] the new setting to MonthRotate will not take effect on the same month that it was done; so I will definitely have to wait until June 10th [the following month] to confirm this feature of vnstat.

Source [[SOLVED] vnstat not changing the start of the month [day]](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324673)